# Get training data little by little

Tags: machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I am working on cifar 10 with azure ml, but it takes too much time for learning because there are too many data. Tensorflow have next_batch function to get training data little by little. I would also like to use it in azure ml. How can I get data little by little and speed up learning per epoch?

Answer (score 0):

Incremental training of DNNs is not supported in Azure ML Studio. I suggest taking a look into Azure ML Workbench with gives you programmatic access to the algorithms to do minibatch training.

See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/preview/how-to-use-gpu